# In Vim, how do I make visual line selection for a block of code?

Tags: vim

For example, in HTML I want to select an entire element. I could do <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, and keep hitting <kbd>J</kbd> until I've selected all the lines, but that's cumbersome. Typing `vat` doesn't do what I want either -- it goes into *visual* mode, not *visual line* mode. The problem with not having *visual line* is that when I yank the text, its not yanking the first line's indentation.

Comment: What is the block? Is it some text inside the brackets? Which kind of brackets?

Comment: In HTML, I have a properly formatted element, with lots of elements inside. I want to visually select the entire element in line mode.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just do `vat` as usual, then press `shift-v` to have linewise selection.

Comment: Oh, wow, can't believe I didn't see that. Simple and intuitive. Thanks!

Comment: This is brilliant!

Comment: I suppose a downside of this is when using `vit`, in which case it will still select the opening tag itself (when what you really want is inner content).

Comment: @BenDavis it depends on how your does html look like.

Comment: Or... you could start out with line mode: `Vat` is equivalent to `vatV` (except with some weird nesting where you have multiple tags on a line, where linewise mode doesn't make much sense), but shorter :)

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to install [matchit](https://github.com/adelarsq/vim-matchit) plugin, which provides extended functionality for <kbd>%</kbd>. Particularly it allows to jump between matching `HTML` tags using <kbd>%</kbd>.

After that, put cursor on opening `HTML` tag (on first letter of the tag, not `<` symbol) and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>, then <kbd>%</kbd>.

This will do line selection from the line you put cursor to the line containing the closing tag.

Comment: I tried this (I have matchit installed using Vundle), but when I press <kbd>%</kbd> it just jumps between the opening and closing brackets (`<` and `>`).

Comment: Navigate inside the tag, then if `matchit` installed you will jump to the closing tag. I mean, if you have tag `<sometag>`, put cursor to letter `s`